# ¿Como puedo habilitar el file_get_contents() en PHP 8.1?

Tags: php, http, url, curl

Estoy programando en PHP 8.1 y necesito utilizar la función `file_get_contents()` pero cada vez que ejecuta esta función me da un problema, he buscado por internet y dice que debo de poner en las php.inisiguientes líneas:

```
allow_url_fopen=On 
allow_url_include=On
```

El caso es que esta última línea he leído que ha sido obsoleta a partir de la versión PHP 7.4, ¿hay alguna equivalencia a esa línea o una equivalencia a `file_get_contents()`? El código se que está bien porque lo ejecutó en un servidor local (XAMPP) y me funciona perfectamente, debe ser que tienen una versión de PHP anterior a la 7.4

(el php.ini lo he puesto en la carpeta raíz y en el directorio donde se encuentra el archivo php que quiero ejecutar) (también decir que he intentado sustituir el `file_get_contents()`con las funciones del cURL y me funciona en el XAMPP pero no en mi servidor)

Espero haberme explicado, muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: No necesitas nada para habilitar la función `file_get_contents()` en PHP 8.1, estaría bien que detallases "el problema" ¿algún mensaje de error? ¿miraste el error_log? Si utilizas la función para leer un archivo local (en el servidor), no deberías tener problema, salvo por permisos. Pero parece que la quieres para leer de una URL, en este caso lo mejor es que uses cURL, te permite obtener más información sobre posibles problemas, por ejemplo puedes comprobar el código de respuesta HTTP. Quizá un problema de conectividad porque tu hosting cape por seguridad, cURL es lo mejor para determinarlo.

Comment: *...el php.ini lo he puesto en la carpeta raíz y en el directorio donde se encuentra el archivo php que quiero ejecutar* ... pues me parece que no tienes claro cuál es el sentido del archivo `php.ini` y debes tener cuidado con intentar modificarlo. Para entender mejor el sentido de `php.ini` te aconsejo que [leas aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/configuration.file.php). En cuanto al problema que planteas, no aparece claro cuál es en concreto. Como ya sugirió @JoséCarlosPHP, revisa el log de errores y dinos qué error da y es mucho mejor que uses cURL.

Comment: Te recomiendo hacer un phpinfo(); para ver realmente que está activo y que no.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.